# AWS IAM role does not exist or is not attachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I encountered the following error when launching an AWS VPC from the command line interface following a quickstart guide [here](https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-aws-biotech-blueprint-cdk/).

Commands used:

```
git clone https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-aws-biotech-blueprint-cdk.git
cd quickstart-aws-biotech-blueprint-cdk
npm install
npm run build
cdk bootstrap
npm run build && cdk deploy
```

Error message:

```
AwsBiotechBlueprint: creating CloudFormation changeset...
11:38:13 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role                                   
| ConfigEnabledPr
omi...corderRoleFC6F886B
Policy arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSConfigRole does not exist or is not 
attachable. (Service
: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchEntity; Request ID: 
f03b794e-7aa5-4f24-
899e-2aefaa6e8fb3; Proxy: null)
```

I am using an IAM user (not Root) and the error appears to indicate that "AWSConfigRole" policy is not associated with my user.  To correct this error I added the "AWSConfigRole" permissions through the IAM management console via my web browser.

Unfortunately when I rerun the steps in the quickstart I still encounter the exact same error.

How can I ensure the updated permissions from the IAM management console are being properly communicated to the command line interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I still encounter the exact same error.

Because this policy should be setup for **IAM role** for Config service to assume, not your IAM user. Also `AWSConfigRole` policy has been long [deprecated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/security-iam-awsmanpol.html). Now you should be using `AWS_ConfigRole` instead explaining why it can't be used anymore.

It seems that the template you are deploying is **old** and not up to date. Its better to [make an issue](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-aws-biotech-blueprint-cdk/issues) about this to the devs of the template, as they should update it.